# Do you need to pass in template types to functions that accept template objects in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'm experimenting with lists in Coq:

```
Inductive list (A : Type) : Type := 
    | empty : list A 
    | cons (n : A) (l : list A).
Arguments empty {A}.
Arguments cons {A} n l.
```

The `Arguments` statements at the bottom (in addition to some Notation statements) allow me to write `[1;2;3]` and let the interpreter figure out what type should fill `A`, rather than specifying that `A` should be `nat`.

However, when I write a `length` function for my `list` objects, my approach throws errors:

```
Fixpoint length (l : list A) : nat :=
    match l with 
    | empty => 0
    | cons n cdr => 1 + (length cdr)
    end.
```

It expects that the passed-in lists are actually lists of the `A` type, instead of recognizing `A` as a template type.

The standard library takes this approach:

```
Definition length (A : Type) : list A -> nat :=
  fix length l :=
  match l with
   | nil => O
   | _ :: l' => S (length l')
  end.
```

where you're expected to pass in the type of the list, like so:

```
Compute length nat [1;2;3]. (* 3 *)
```

This seems like a serious drawback. I can't seem to define an `Argument` statement that solves this problem like before. Is there really no other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the `Arguments` statements for `list` are not responsible for letting you write `[1;2;3]`. That is a separate `Notation`. Furthermore, if an argument is explicit, you can pass the expression `_` for it, to request Coq to fill it in. (I.e. the `Notation` `[x; ...; z]` is possible to define with or without the `Arguments`)

```
Inductive mylist (A : Type) : Type := mynil | mycons (x : A) (xs : mylist A).
Notation "[[ ]]" := (mynil _). (* note that I *can* pass in the explicit type argument without actually knowing it *)
Notation "[[ x ; .. ; y ]]" := (mycons _ x .. (mycons _ y [[]]) .. ).
Check [[]].
Check [[1;2;3]].
```

Understanding this already makes an explicitly type-passing `length` not actually that bad to use

```
Fixpoint mylength (A : Type) (xs : mylist A) : nat :=
  match xs with
  | mynil _ => 0
  | mycons _ _ xs => S (mylength A xs)
  end.
Compute (mylength _ [[1; 2; 3]]). (* Coq solves for [_ := nat] itself *)
```

All that aside, you declare an argument to be implicit by putting it in braces, how else? For a definition like `mylength` which was originally defined with an explicit argument, `Arguments` can change that:

```
Arguments mylength {A} xs.
Compute (mylength [[1; 2; 3]]).
(* Indeed, the standard library has Arguments length [A] xs, which is similar to using {A} (read the documentation!) and lets you say *)
Compute (length [1; 2; 3]).
```

But it is more usual to just define functions with implicit arguments from the outset.

```
Fixpoint mylength2 {A : Type} (xs : mylist A) : nat := (* implicit A *)
  match xs with
  | mynil _ => 0
  | mycons _ _ xs => S (mylength2 xs)
  end.
Compute (mylength2 [[1; 2; 3]]).
```

(You can't *not* declare `A` as a parameter of `mylength`/`mylength2`, since the parameter type `mylist A` needs `A` to be in scope to make sense.)

Comment: I paraphrased a bit at the beginning but this solution is really nice, I was not aware that you could define functions with implicit arguments

Comment: @CharlesAverill, you can also set some flags to get automatic implicit arguments without needing to remember to write the curly braces. Take a look at [this section of the refman](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/extensions/implicit-arguments.html#mode-for-automatic-declaration-of-implicit-arguments).